# How to make all calls from an Azure WebJob originate from the same external IP?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-virtual-network

I am working on a WebJob that periodically retrieves information from an API on a remote server.

In order to be able to access the API, my IP address must be whitelisted, but I am not sure how to achieve that for a WebJob.

So my question is: how do I configure a static outgoing IP through which my WebJob can access the internet?

(Assuming the WebJob is deployed to an App Service Plan, not a VM)

Answer (score 2):

You already have a good answer from @junnas above.

Just want to add that there is a way to find out all possible IP’s that your app could use.

Here’s a link to MS documentation that covers your question in detail- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses#find-outbound-ips

> You can find the set of all possible outbound IP addresses your app can use, regardless of pricing tiers, by looking for the possibleOutboundIPAddresses property.

```
az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query possibleOutboundIpAddresses --output tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

An App Service has a set of outgoing IP addresses which you can find from its Properties:

[image: App Service Outbound IP addresses]

It uses one of them at random for outbound communication and you cannot decide which.
My suggestion, whitelist all of them.

Just beware though, those addresses *can* change, though they don't change often.

Comment: Is there no way to narrow it down to a single address? More importantly, is there no way to guarantee the addresses won't ever change? I am communicating with a mission critical component protected by an ip whitelist, and if I lose connection to it, people will lose their head.

Comment: Then you can't use a shared infrastructure like app service.

Comment: With an app service environment maybe?